# Do the policies attached to IAM groups take precedence over the policies attached to individual IAM users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, identity-management, policies

I have a question
let's assume I attached IAM policy "EC2FullAccess" to a user
and then I added that specific user to a group
but that group don't have "EC2FullAccess" Policy
is he will still able to access to EC2?

Comment: The standard guide for policy evaluation logic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, one doesn't take precedence over the other. They are "combined". The user would have all the permissions applied to the group, plus all the permissions applied to their individual account.

The exception is a `Deny` statement in a policy, which always takes precedence over any `Allow` statement.